# Is Google Cloud Platform 'Cloud SQL' service IAAS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

with Google cloud platform, cloud SQL you get a lot of options to setup the infrastructure.  Does this mean cloud SQL is infrastructure as a service  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the infrastucture of Cloud SQL is managed by Google and by it's engineers, so, Cloud SQL is PAAS (Plaform As A Service).

Cloud SQL is a docker container built on top of a GCE instance, and Google monitor everything for you, and fix the Cloud SQL instance automatically if something goes wrong (Sometimes Google software engineers have to perform some actions to fix some issues if the instance is stuck). So, the only thing that you have to take care of is to store and query your data.

Also, Cloud SQL offers a lot of interesting features, such as, failover replicas, read replicas, user and database adminitration, etc.

So, in Cloud SQL, Google doesn't just sell the infrastucture to create databases, but also the application itself and the monitoring tools too.

Comment: Do you have a link/reference for this comment: "Cloud SQL is a docker container built on top of a GCE instance"?

Comment: If it's a PAAS should not the scaling of the instance happen automatically. In cloud SQL, you have to specify the size of the instance you want.

Comment: @IA39 you can select attributes of the underlying infrastructure, but you don't directly manage the infrastructure.  Automatic scaling and/or seamless scaling can be significant product differentiators, but they are not defining components of what is or isn't PaaS.  Similarly, choosing an underlying storage type (e.g. magnetic disks or SSD) or having to declare maximum allocated storage capacity wouldn't disqualify a system from being PaaS.